# How to show a gloabl message on a user profile page (in back end)?

Tags: custom-field, users, admin-menu, profiles, user-roles

I want to show a global message for all users in their profile page. 
I do not want to edit `profile.php` 
what is the `hook` to do this?

Basically I want to add a `div` to show a `paragraph` below the message div id `<div id="message" class="updated">` and above the `<form id="your-profile" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" action="http://localhost/wordpress/gantry/demo2/wp-admin/profile.php">`

[image: into this]

Comment: How would you feel about a javascript solution?

Answer (score 1):

add this code to your function.php

```
<?php
function showMessage($message, $errormsg = false)
{
    if ($errormsg) {
        echo '<div id="message" class="error">';
    }
    else {
        echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade">';
    }
    echo "<p><strong>$message</strong></p></div>";
} 

function showAdminMessages()
{
    showMessage("This is my message.", true);
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'showAdminMessages');
?>
```

Comment: This works well and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible, there just isn't a hook to use in `wp-admin/edit-use.php`.

The closest you can come is to place something under **Personal Options**, although this hook is called at the end of that section so this will show your message a little way down the page -

```
add_action('personal_options', 'my_edit_user_admin_message');
function my_edit_user_admin_message(){
?>
    <tr class="show-admin-bar user-admin-bar-front-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><label for="admin_bar_front"><?php _e( 'Admin message' )?></label></th>
        <td><fieldset>
                <legend class="screen-reader-text"><span><?php _e('Admin message') ?></span></legend>
                <label><p id="my-admin-message">This is my message.</p></label><br />
        </fieldset></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

While not technically valid (most, but not all, browsers will correct it) you can instead use the code below, which will force your message to the top of the **Personal Options** section, but still under the header.

However it comes with the recommendation that you don't use it, as it's invalid to nest a `block` element inside a `table` element.

```
add_action('personal_options', 'my_edit_user_admin_message');
function my_edit_user_admin_message(){
?>
    <div id="my-admin-message">
        <p>This is my message.</p>
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Although this answer may work, I think namira's answer using 'admin_notices' hook is the better choice.